# Custom paging in ASP Gridview using stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, custompaging

I'm trying to create a GridView with custom paging. I have very large data so In order to Increase ten Speed I'm trying to do Custom Paging.

I wrote a SQL Server stored procedure that takes input parameters `SelectedPageNumber`, `SelectedPageSize` and gives the `DataTable` filled with the resulting rows belonging to the particular page. The stored procedure also has a `MaxPageNumber` as output parameter.

I'm able to bind the data of the page to the GridView but I'm not able to figure out how to show the page numbers up to the `MaxPageNumber` value taken as a stored procedure.

I'm using .Net Framework 4.0

It might be a duplicate but I could not find the solution.

Can you help me out ???

Comment: If you are performing a custom paging, then I guess it would be better to use a lighter control like `Repeater` instead of `GridView`, And of course you would have to render a custom pager too.

Comment: If you want to show Page numbers/MaxPageNumber then you can use Label control for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Pager using `Repeater` control, Something like this

```
// These are your outputs from that SP
int MaxPageNumber = 10,
    CurrentPageNumber = 4;

void BindPager()
{
    DataTable PagerData = new DataTable();
    PagerData.Columns.Add("pageNo");
    for (int i = 1; i < MaxPageNumber; i++)
      PagerData.Rows.Add(i);
    pager.DataSource = PagerData;
    pager.DataBind();
}

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="pager" onitemcommand="pager_ItemCommand" 
        onitemdatabound="pager_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="pageNo" 
                   Text='<%# Eval("pageNo") %>' 
                   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("pageNo") %>'
                   CommandName="DoPaging" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void pager_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Code to highlight current page
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
     Button pageNo = e.Item.FindControl("pageNo") as Button;
     if (pageNo == null) return;
     if (pageNo.Text == CurrentPageNumber.ToString())
        pageNo.BackColor = Color.Blue;
     else
        pageNo.BackColor = Color.Gray;
  }
}

protected void pager_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
  // perform your paging here according to page number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the page numbers you can create a List of integers from MinPageNumber to MaxPageNumber, bind the list to a Repeater-Control as the DataSource and let the Repeater display each page number. Depending on the current page number you might have to recreate that list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom paging then you have to create a custom page control to display the page numbers. You can place the custom pager below the gridview and on click event on the page number rebind the grid.